# Can this integral be evaluated numerically?

Tags: integration, numerical-methods, computational-mathematics, greens-function

I am working with periodic Green's functions for a scattering problem and the form of the Green's function given is as follows -

$$G(x, y) = -\sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}^2} e^{i n \cdot \alpha} \int_0^E \frac{1}{4\pi t} e^{\omega^2 t - \frac{|x - n - y|^2}{4t}} dt$$

This is supposed to be in a computationally friendly form in that it will rapidly converge (Ewald's method - http://www.math.ntua.gr/~papanico/publications/paper19.pdf)

However this integral doesn't seem valid to me considering the domain is from $0$ to some arbitrary constant $E$, yet we have $\frac{1}{t}$ in the integrand. So is it possible to integrate this? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's true that the integrand is not defined at $t=0$, but because $\exp(-c/t)$ goes very rapidly to $0$ as $t \to 0+$ for any $c > 0$, the integral will converge as long as $x - n - y \ne 0$, and the sum will converge as long as $x - y \notin \mathbb Z^2$.  If you're going to use a numerical integration method that will evaluate the integrand at the endpoints, it's important to tell it that the integrand is $0$ at $t=0$.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up! Anything you can say about the situation when $x = y$? What value is appropriate for the Green's function in this case?

Comment: When $x = y$ the exponential doesn't help, and you have a $1/t$ singularity: the integral diverges.

Comment: Ok, I suppose I can just neglect any contribution in that case. I have a follow up question related to the Green's function that is supposed to be combined with this one to give the overall Green's function - http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1703174/can-this-integral-be-evaluated-numerically - if you get a chance maybe you could take a look at it.

Comment: Sorry the correct link is - http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1704565/can-this-integral-be-computed-int-e-infty-frac14-pi-t-e-omega2-t