# Can this integral be computed? $\int_E^{\infty} \frac{1}{4\pi t} e^{\omega^2 t - \frac{|x - n - y|^2}{4t}} dt$

Tags: integration, numerical-methods, computational-mathematics, greens-function

I am working with periodic Green's functions for a scattering problem and the form of the Green's function given is as follows -

$$G(x, y) = -\sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}^2} e^{i n \cdot \alpha} \int_E^{\infty} \frac{1}{4\pi t} e^{\omega^2 t - \frac{|x - n - y|^2}{4t}} dt$$

This is supposed to be in a computationally friendly form in that it will rapidly converge (Ewald's method - http://www.math.ntua.gr/~papanico/publications/paper19.pdf)

This is related to my previous question - [Can this integral be evaluated numerically?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1703174/can-this-integral-be-evaluated-numerically) - and the integral in that post is in fact  possible to integrate as shown in the answer. However with the integral in this post we have an integrand with $e^t$ and a limit of infinity so I can't see how this can be valid?

(As an aside, this Green's function and the one in my previous post are added together to obtain the true Green's function.)

Comment: You are right. It obviously evaluates to $+\infty$.

Comment: I should add that $\omega$ could be complex, if that makes any difference.

Comment: Hmmm...and I suppose it does make a difference if by squaring it, it can 'rotate' a complex number with negative imaginary part into the negative real plane?

Comment: The question is whether $\omega^2$ has a positive real part. If it does, then the integral is $+\infty$.

Comment: So it seems we need a complex $\omega$ with $\Im(\omega) > \Re(\omega)$

Comment: What is known about the value of E?